# Is there a way to add a class to the component root element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

Except for adding the class in html.

I mean something like that:
In html

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

In js

```
angular.module('app').component('myComponent', {
  template: '<div class="inner-element">Inner element</div>',
  className: 'outer-element' <--- wanted property
});
```

This is how I want it to look after render:

```
<my-component class="outer-element"> <--- that's what I want to get
  <div class="inner-element">Inner element</div>
</my-component>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @RafaelGadottiBachovas, I want to add a class to the root element.

Comment: I don't know how can I describe this more extended.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could specify controller that adds class on component init

```
controller: function($element) {
  this.$onInit = function() {
    $element.addClass('outer-element')
  };
}
```

But this kinda goes against encapsulation and such.

Comment: Thanks! But if there isn't special property so how should I do this in more 'encapsulation and such' way? I need the class to organize my CSS.

Comment: @through.a.haze Ideally parent template should add classes to elements (components) it renders depending on its own data and state. Can't you simply use tag name (my-component {background-color: navy;}) to organize your CSS?

Comment: I can but I'd prefer to use classname in CSS. But anyway thanks to you! I accept your answer.

Comment: How can you achieve flexible-component-layout without "breaking encapsulation"? (Imagine to have a `Timeline` component with multiple `Event` child-components with the need of being `flex-100` or `flex-50` based on device width)